# foreignKey seems not working in a belongsTo clause

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

**PROBLEM**

I'm using sequelize to make an auto-generated query with a JOIN and I get that :
`` SELECT [...] FROM `weapon` AS `weapon` LEFT OUTER JOIN `stat` AS `mainStat` ON `weapon`.`ID` = `mainStat`.`ID` WHERE `weapon`.`type` = 'polearm'; ``

However, the ON clause is incorrect, in fact, I want that :
`` [...] ON `weapon`.`mainStatID` = `mainStat`.`ID` [...] ``
Here is the associations I declared :

```js
Weapon.hasOne( Stat, { foreignKey: 'mainStatID', as: 'mainStat' });
Stat.belongsTo( Weapon );
```

`Stat.belongsTo( Weapon );` Just don't change anything.

Maybe I didn't understand something with `.hasOne()` and `.belongsTo()` concept ?

**MODELS**

Here is the two concerned Models :

```
const Weapon = sequelize.define('weapon', {
    ID            : { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    name          : { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    shortName     : { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    type          : { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    rarity        : { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    baseAtk       : { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    mainStatID    : { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    description   : { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    maxStack      : { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false },
    optionalEffect: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true }
},
{
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
})

const Stat = sequelize.define('stat', {
    ID         : { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    displayName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    shortName  : { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    value      : { type: DataTypes.FLOAT, allowNull: false, get() {return parseFloat(this.getDataValue('value'))} }
},
{
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
})
```

**Using mysql and sequelize 6.25.4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should remove the explicit field definition for the foreign key:

```
mainStatID: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
```

Secondly, if you would like a foreign-key field of MainStatID in the Weapon table then the relationship should be:

```
Weapon.belongsTo(Stat, { as: 'MainStat' });
```

Comment: That's what I don't understand tbh, why Weapon would belongs to Stat, since logically, a stat belongs to a Weapon.

Also, why should I remove the explicit field definition ?

Comment: The documentation does not mention explicitly defining the foreign-key field, so presumably you don't need to and shouldn't (https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/). It may seem counter-intuitive for it to be that way around, but the `MainStatID` field in the weapon table is saying which Stat owns that Weapon. That is how the belongsTo relationship works. If that's how you want the tables/models setup then that's the relationship to use.